# The difference between BuiltinFuntionType and BuiltinMethodType

Tags: python-3.x

There's no strict definition to distinguish BuiltinFuntionType and BuiltinMethodType in official documentation.

Observe the following codes

```
import types
In [133]: total_builtins = dir(__builtins__)
In [138]: builtin_functions =  [i for i in total_builtins if 
isinstance(eval(i),types.BuiltinFunctionType)]
In [139]: builtin_methods = [i for i in total_builtins if
 isinstance(eval(i),types.BuiltinMethodType)]
In [140]: builtin_functions ==  builtin_methods
Out[140]: True
```

Check their types

```
In [142]: {type(getattr(__builtins__, name)) for name in builtin_functions}
Out[142]: {builtin_function_or_method}
```

The boolean keyword 'or' indicates that the interpreter does not distinguish them during implementation.
If that, why not combine them?

There's an example in documentation which explains the `built-in methods`

> An example of a built-in method is alist.append(), assuming alist is a list object. In this case, the special read-only attribute **self** is set to the object denoted by alist.[3. Data model — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)

So the builtin methods are the builtin types' methods like (`list.append` or `dict.update`).

However, it does not explain `__builtins__`.

What's difference of BuiltinFuntionType and BuiltinMethodType?

Comment: There seems to be no difference. From `types`: `BuiltinFunctionType = type(len);
BuiltinMethodType = type([].append)     # Same as BuiltinFunctionType`